How can I perform retopology on my mesh without ruining it's original look?
I have some meshes in my Blender files that I would like to optimize for animating and rigging.  It also needs to feature slight beveling at the edges when sub-divided. How can I modify my mesh without losing the original look of it? I've already tried the remesh option, but that ruined it. Is there a "one size fits all" retopology method that I could use?


Making a copy? You might need to be more clear

@Emir What do you mean by "Making a copy"? And what would you like me to clarify?

You can make copies for your meshes in Blender by selecting the mesh and hitting Shift + D on your keyboard. By doing so, you can experiment with retopology to get different result that could serve your final goal without messing the original one

I think you need to show us a typical mesh. I think it's fair to say there is no 'one size fits all' for truly optimizing a mesh while retaining its essential character.. yet.

Perhaps you could use the shrinkwrap technique, whereby you create a copy of your original mesh to use as a shrinkwrap target (like a template)  and then shrinkwrap your refined topology back on the original? Hard to say whether this is any use without seeing exactly what you are trying to do.
